# Eclipse -> Team -> Add to version control

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I've added a new file to a project in Eclipse.  But I'm not having any luck adding this new file to CVS for version control.  CVS/Eclipse keeps error it out when I try to do that.  Below is what I did:
1) On Eclipse/RAD IDE, right click on the new file and select Team -> Add to version control.

Below is the error I gotton:

```
Errors saving CVS synchronization information to disk. Please fix the problems listed below and then update the affected resources from the CVS repository.
    Resource '/Boss/conf/CVS' does not exist.
    Resource '/Boss/conf/CVS' does not exist.
```

When I click on the "Show CVS Console" button.  I see this:

```
***
cvs add -kkv "/Boss/conf/mobileConnect.pcml"
    cvs server: scheduling file `conf/mobileConnect.pcml' for addition
    cvs server: use 'cvs commit' to add this file permanently
ok (took 0:00.421)
```

Comment: It seems like "cvs server: scheduling file `conf/mobileConnect.pcml' for addition" and "cvs server: use 'cvs commit' to add this file permanently" are not error messages.  Those are normal messages when sending add command to cvs server.  For some reason, eclipse cvs plugin thinks that they are error.  I also tried perform commit on that new file and gotton the exact same error.  Looks like eclipse plugin mis-intepreted the message and abort the commit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the subdirectory *conf* was not yet added to the repository. This must be done before you can add any file there.